# Can a MQTT broker also be a client?

Tags: mqtt

I have the doubt if a MQTT Broker also can be a client? Or I must need to separate and get a dispositive to act as a broker and another as a client. I'm not finding information on internet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly, what you are looking for is MQTT bridging.

This is where one broker acts as a client to a second (or multiple) broker and based on config copies messages on topics between the 2 brokers.

How this is configured depends on which broker you are using, but the concept is part of the spec (I don't think it's optional off the top of my head) so all brokers should support it